# C pointer convertion cause memory access violation

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I'm trying to migrate an old project from Borland BCC 5 to Qt 5.6.3 with Microsoft MSVC 2015 64bit compiler.

The following code is a model of original work. It works as expected in Visual Studio 2015 and Borland BCC 5, However, when I try to run it in Qt 5.6.3 with Qt Creator 3.6.1. It throws an error as "*hcID" is not accessible.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void (*ProcFoo)  (void *pvData, unsigned long ulBarTag);

static char* gpcID = NULL;

typedef struct FooType
{
    ProcFoo       pfFoo;      ///< pointer to Foo callback function
    unsigned long ulBarTag;   ///< base id
} FooType;

FooType* pFoo = NULL;

void RegisterAsFoo(unsigned long ulBarTag, ProcFoo pfFoo)
{
    pFoo = (FooType*)malloc(sizeof(FooType));

    pFoo->ulBarTag = ulBarTag;
    pFoo->pfFoo = pfFoo;
}


void GetBarTag(unsigned long *pulBarTag, unsigned long ulBarTag)
{
    *pulBarTag = ulBarTag;
}


int main()
{
    char s[] = "Some Value";
    gpcID = s;
    char ** hcID = NULL;

    RegisterAsFoo((unsigned long)&gpcID, (ProcFoo)GetBarTag);

    pFoo->pfFoo(&hcID, pFoo->ulBarTag);


    // after the execution, the hcID is still NULL in Qt 5.6.3, however, 
    // it is valid in Visual Studio 2015 and Borland BCC 5.
    char* result = (*hcID);

    return 1;
}
```

Thanks if you have any comments or ideas!

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Please pick one.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart thanks for comment. I removed the C++ flag.

Comment: @Risheng Are you sure C is the right choice? Qt is a C++ library, and C does not have `<iostream>` or `new`.

Comment: Now your code is tagged as C but has C++ code in it: `pFoo = new FooType;` Perhaps the first stepisode is to figure out what programming language you're using.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Sorry for miss-understanding.  I replaced the new method with the original malloc. This is a very old project, with a core written in pure C, and some extra dll in C++. Now my team need to migrate to Qt platform, with Windows MSVC compiler.

Comment: I've really only glanced over this, but given hcID is already a pointer to pointer are you sure you want to further pass it by address to pfFoo()?

Comment: This question deserves a good de-foo-bar-ication! Now it looks like you are trying to implement a C-implementation of C-like cast operation ;)

Comment: @aschepler. The project is actually a mix of C core and C++ Dlls,  The code posted is actually from different files, and to make it run I changed it unconsciously with C++ syntax. Now I replaced it with malloc, as the original work.

Comment: @whoasked No I don't, but these code exist in my project already for almost 20 years. :(

Comment: Can we see the actual error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is in the

```
(unsigned long)
```

cast which works for 32 bit.
Use

```
(unsigned long long)
```

instead. You need to do the replacement all over the place.

Otherwise, get rid of the int to pointer conversion or use a 32 bit compiler instead

Comment: Thanks for comment, your are right! that's exactly the problem :)

Comment: Sorry but it's not me dowvoted. someone downvoted your answer, as well as my question :(

Comment: That is the way it is, no problem.